# How do you say, "What's your problem?" in Mandarin？

Tags: translation

I want to know how to say, "What's your problem?" as an insult in Mandarin.

Comment: 你有毛病啊？！//你有什麼毛病(嗎)？//搞什麼？

Comment: @FarnzSeager you can post that as an answer

Comment: 你有病啊? to reply that insult, 你有药啊! to reply that reply: 你能吃多少? to continue: 你有多少? Continue 你吃多少我有多少. Continue 你有多少我吃多少. Then you can repeat the last two sentences...

Comment: Maybe someone could clarify if [怎么搞的](https://youdao.com/w/eng/怎么搞的) is an option (?).

Answer (score 1):

你很多問題勒神經病嗎““5”4””4
再來你有病嗎
是沒去看醫生嗎

Answer (score 0):

Its original meaning is

> 你的问题是什么?

There is another popular saying

> 你怎么回事啊？

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to express

> What's your problem?

this in the sense of

> Do you have a problem with that?

you can say

> 你有什么**意见**吗？

**意见** means, in general, *opinion*, *comment* or *suggestion*. (Compare with 建议 which possesses a similar meaning yet with a softer connotation). The former may suggest there is a variance in opinions to the extent of contention,  while the latter describes a suggestion in the sense of a non-dictating recommendation.

Depending on your tone of voice and context, **意见** may convey a different attitude, but it tends to sound argumentative in most cases. [Consult this](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/6209673.html?qbl=relate_question_0).

**Do note** that this way of expression might get you in trouble, so use your words wisely! :)

Answer (score 0):

> 你有毛病啊?!

Or even simpler

> 你有病啊?!

In a similar vein, if you want to call someone crazy

> 你疯了吗??